# Route [people.comments] not defined

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7, laravel-routing, named-routing

help me to find the problem, the laravel project gives error before loading

> Route [people.comments] not defined

I copied and pasted the route name, copied and pasted the working routes, but no, it doesn't work.

```
    Route::post('/people/comments', 'Admin\PeopleController@comments')->name('people.comments');
```

And It worked when I changed method POST to GET
Route::get('/people/comments', 'Admin\PeopleController@comments')->name('people.comments');

I am using this route inside a JAVASCRIPT

```
      let url = '{{ route("people.comments") }}';
```

Now the question is why it is worked when I changed post to get? and why it is not working in POST ?
(I don't have routes with same name)
THANKS

Comment: POST request always perform through form.

Answer (score 0):

This was my error two posts with same address and same method

```
 Route::post('/people/comments', 'Admin\PeopleController@comments')->name('people.comments');
 Route::post('/people/comments', 'Admin\PeopleController@blogs')->name('people.blogs');
```